# __defineSetter__ replacement for firefox 3.5.x and up

Tags: javascript

It seems that `__defineSetter__` no longer works in firefox latest version. It works in Chrome.

do you know Any replacement function that does the same thing and also works in other browsers like IE, Opera,Safari?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`__defineGetter__` and `__defineSetter__` are still in the latest Firefox and I don't believe there are plans to remove them in the short term. In the long term, ECMAScript 5 specifies a different form of getters and setters that will eventually make its way into all browsers.

Here is an example of ECMAScript 5 getters and setters. It currently works in IE 9, Chrome 5, Safari 5: see [here](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/) for a compatibility table.

```
var o = {};
Object.defineProperty(o, "p", {
    get: function() {
        return "A property";
    },
    set: function(val) {
        alert("Setting " + val + "!");
    }
});
```

**Edit**

As requested, here's a working example of `__defineGetter__` and `__defineSetter__`, equivalent to the ES5 code above:

```
var o = {};
o.__defineGetter__("p", function() {
    return "A property";
});
o.__defineSetter__("p", function(val) {
    alert("Setting " + val + "!");
});
```

Comment: can you provide me your working examples of __defineGetter__ and __defineSetter__  ?

Answer (score 0):

for firefox you should use the "watch" method.

```
 if(Object.prototype.watch){
    instance.watch("property", function(id, prevValue, newValue){

            //do operaions here on the value ---

         return newValue  
  }
}
```

... where instance is the object and the property is the actual property you want to watch for changes.